# Populating html list from a file

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have several `ul` on the homepage of my app. Enclosed in each `li` I have 6 different variables(section#, id, start, end, img, title)

I'm going to be updating the content of the lists constantly so It would be good if I was to be able to populate the page dynamically from a file with this variables organized in an easier to read/update manner.

Here is one list on my app:

```html
<li data-section="number" 
    id="uLAD-IrB8B0" 
    data-start="20" 
    data-end="40">
    <img src="sample.png"/>
    <div class="title">Some title</div>
</li>
```

I understand this can be accomplish with php. However, I'm not so sure if this is the best alternative or how to move forward on this direction.

Comment: You may start with a file, but eventually things will scale up and you will have to resort to database, so why not start now?

Comment: I see, I'm all about doing things right. I assume I would need php to connect to the database, correct? Also, Should I make a table for each section?

Comment: PHP, C#, Ruby, Python, C, C++, etc, etc, etc. Any backend language can connect to a database. PHP is probably the easiest to use coupled with html. Database design on the other hand is a topic on its own right. I would recommend though one single table to hold the information on the line. (ID, section?, start, end, img_src, title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where your data is coming from, and how you want to update this data.

If you want to update it from files (or a database), you will probably want an AJAX type of architecture. The way that would work is on your client, you'd have some javascript that makes a query to a php script (possibly sending some data), and receives a response with some new data, then the javascript would write that data into the attributes you have above.

However, if your new data is coming from user input, you could get away with just javascript. So, in this case, you might have a text field (or other input fields) that have an onChange handler, which would update the attributes and content you show above.

If you give some more context, I might be able to give you a better answer.

**Edit:**
I would recommend doing some research on AJAX development. This page looks like a good one http://www.sitepoint.com/build-your-own-ajax-web-apps/

Once you have learned how AJAX works, you'll have a better understanding of the components involved (javascript, php, databases, etc). (ie: you'll know what you don't know) :)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Well as of right now, I just want to be able to update html content without having to manually insert the fields in the html but I do care about doing things the right way and considering future development of the app. What solution would you suggest? I'm interested in learning new technics but I also need to keep it simple so it still is something I can accomplish given my experience with php and databases.

Comment: "I do care about doing things the right way"

imho, if this was my first time, I would focus on making something functionnal rather than optimal. Once you understand how things work, you can then think about making things the right way. You sound like you are new to theses things, so this is my advice.

Comment: @Tkrugg Thank you. So, what would be the functional way?

Comment: @irm I think what he means is simply to give a shot at it it, and make something that works the way you want, and then after you have learned the basics, refine your code to work efficiently and "correctly"